# PCRE metro app visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, pcre

I am trying to link pcre.lib in my metro app on visual studio 2013. I want to use the library in a .cpp file (the pcre project contains .c files). 
I tried  to build pcre project and use the generated lib file and the original headers. The problem is on compiling, because on each function i use from pcre library it says (the next example is for pcre_study function) :
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_pcre_study

I want to mention that i linked the .lib file correctly and i added all the paths required. Probably the problem is when i am building the pcre project.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Did you strictly follow the steps from the `NON-AUTOTOOLS-BUILD` file?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried to link the library in a simple windows console application but i receive the same error.